# How do you refer to foreign titles in APA6?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I'm familiar with the example for when I am citing a part of a [foreign source](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/translations/) but I have questions about referring to foreign titled work. I have written papers before in MLA, but I am required to write in APA6 for my next paper.

**The example from the website:**

> In text:
> Research has addressed that “Les jeunes qui terminent un placement à l’âge de la majorité dans le cadre du système de protection de la jeunesse sont plus vulnérables” [Youth who finish a placement at the age of majority in the framework of the youth protection system are more vulnerable] (Bussières, St-Germain, Dubé, & Richard, 2017, p. 354).

And in the reference list:

> Reference list:
> Bussières, E.-L., St-Germain, A., Dubé, M., & Richard, M.-C. (2017). Efficacité et efficience des programmes de transition à la vie adulte: Une revue systématique [Effectiveness and efficiency of adult transition programs: A systematic review]. *Canadian Psychology/Psychologie canadienne*, 58, 354–365. https://doi.org/10.1037/cap0000104

**My example:**
For example, if I am citing filmmaker Leni Riefenstahl's film *Triumph of the Will* (1935), do I first cite both the English title and the original German title as

> *Triumph des Willens* [*Triumph of the Will, 1935]*

... and then subsequently

> *Triumph of the Will* (1935)

Or is it common practice to just refer to the work's English translation? Is the example proper if I do the translation in the paper?

Do I also use the publication year only once, when first introducing the work, and then only write

> *Triumph of the Will*

In subsequent references to it?